# How to call a button in the constructor in MainPage when app starting using Xamarin iOS c#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have one button who want to call when my app starting.

```
    private async void OnGetWeatherButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code here
    }
```

How to call this button in the constructor to run when the application start ?

Comment: you mean like click it, execute it related code ?

Comment: I want when the application starts the button to be clicked prematurely.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding.. but you could just break all of the buttons code into a method, then call that method a) when the button is clicked normally and b) as your app starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the code to a method that you can call from the constructor:

```
async Task Method(object sender, EventArgs e) {
...
}
```

```
 private async void OnGetWeatherButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Method(sender, e);
    }
```

Then

```
 Public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        await Method(sender, e);
    }
```